# Finding the test with command line MStest

Tags: c#, command-line, mstest

I have hunted for this answer off and on for a couple of days so apologies if I missed the answer.

I have a MS test that I want to run from the command line (eventually in Jenkins). I have the MSTest.exe and the \testcontainer setup but cant get the syntax for the actual test I want to run.

My solution IntegrationTest has two projects (using the Page Model Design Pattern), IntegrationTest and Tests.
FYI \testcontainer points to the assembly (dll) in IntegrationTest

The test I want to run is in Tests/UnitTest1/Login_To_system.
I have tried:

```
/test:Tests.UnitTest1.Login_To_system
/test:Tests/UnitTest1/Login_To_system
```

And a variety of combinations with the results of "cannot be found”

There is no metadata files for tests – using Community 2015.

The whole line, up to one of the test attempts is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /resultsfile:"C:\public\data\trunk\AutomatedTesting\IntegrationTest\TestResults\Results.trx" /testcontainer:"C:\public\data\trunk\AutomatedTesting\IntegrationTest\IntegrationTest\bin\Debug\IntegrationTest.dll" /test:Tests.UnitTest1.Login_To_system
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace FooTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class One
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

Fom the command line:

> C:\tmp\FooTest\FooTest\bin\Release>**mstest
>   /testcontainer:"./FooTest.dll" /test:"FooTest.One."**
>   Microsoft (R) Test
>   Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.23107.0 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading ./FooTest.dll... Starting execution...
>
> Results               Top Level Tests
>   -------               --------------- Passed                FooTest.One.TestMethod1 1/1 test(s) Passed
>
> Summary
>   ------- Test Run Completed.   Passed  1   ---------   Total   1
>   Test Settings: Default Test Settings

So it is "AssemblyName.ClassName.MethodName" to identify a test, in /test
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx